# I must to press spacebar twice to write some code in xCode

Tags: c++, xcode

I just started to use xCode to code C++ recently and found this issue very annoying.
Whenever I start to code something, xCode underlined that and I have to press the spacebar once just to make it disappears and twice for the space letter.
Example:
[image]

Sorry for my English, I'm new at this, please help.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: i found a solution, just change the keyboard layout and it's perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whenever I start to code something, xCode underlined that and I have to press the spacebar once just to make it disappears and twice for the space letter.

You're using a keyboard input method like Telex or Simple Telex, right? With either of those methods enabled I get behavior you describe even in Safari. If you switch to a standard US keyboard, for example, you'll find that the behavior goes away in Xcode and everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, just change the keyboard layout and it's perfect

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10627526)

Comment: @mjp66 he is the author. By the way, I'm pretty sure that he is using a keyboard input method to alternate the input character. Disable it or change to standard keyboard will solve the issue

Comment: @Danh thanks, yes I realized it afterwards, though it still should've been tagged as unsuitable (should've been "This answer should be an edit to the question") ;)